# Can you add/remove KafkaSpouts to Apache Storm Topology Dynamically

Tags: configuration, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have an Apache Storm Topology that accepts messages from multiple Kafka topics.

Currently "multiple" equates to "Two".

As I currently only have two KafkaSpouts to listen to I have hard coded both into my Topology class and coded as follows:-

```
builder.setSpout(SPOUT_ONE_ID, kafkaSpout_A, 1);
builder.setSpout(SPOUT_TWO_ID, kafkaSpout_B, 1);
builder.setBolt(BOLT_ID, myBolt, 1).shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ONE_ID).shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_TWO_ID);
```

however the number of KafkaSpouts will increase over time, each new KafkaSpout will listen to its own unique topic. Each time a new topic appears I will have to implement a code change to my Topology and redeploy it.

I would much rather have my Topology controlled by an external configuration "mechanism" like a disk file or database table. By adding (or removing) Kafka topic details I would like my topology to start (or stop) "listening" to those topics.

Does Apache Storm support this type of dynamic configuartion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache storm currently doesn't support changing topology configuration dynamically. There is an open JIRA items to support as part of [JStorm](https://github.com/alibaba/jstorm). See link : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1335